# Jquery selecting for button

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have a a list that is generated via PHP and SQL and within each styled row I have a favorite button. I want it so when I click the favorite button it toggles a class that changes the color of it.

It works for the first one but any other button in my list doesn't work.

```
     <button id="favorite" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Follow">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
     </button>

     <script>
        $("#favorite").click(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
        });
     </script>
```

I looked on similar questions before posting but I didnt see anything related to what I'm trying to accomplish and even google didn't really help me. I'm sure this is a simple task. I'm fairly new to JQuery

Comment: You need to use a `class` for the button, not an `id`.  `id`s need to be unique.

Comment: While working on generated list using php/mysql, better use `.on`binder like `$(body).on('click','.class',function(){ });`

Comment: Why are you using the body selector when in the above I was trying to get clicks from #favorite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your `id` to a `class`, your code should work fine:

```
 <button class="favorite btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" title="Follow">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
 </button>

 <script>
    $(".favorite").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same ID for multiple elements. Add a class of favourite and try doing this instead:

```
$(".favorite").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
 });
```